# Heroku deployment with angular 6 changes

Tags: angular, express, heroku, angular6

I deployed angular 5 app with this express code.

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
    
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

but as in new angular 6 app we have angular.json instead of angular.cli.json and some outDir options and some changes with the location of dist foler.
Please can anyone suggest some required changes with angular 6. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The `angular.json` change should be irrelevant if your just serving the built artefact.  Just point it at the `index.html` and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved!!
used this code
instead of just dist you will have to add your app name.

```
    const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static('./dist/myappname'));
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join('./dist/myappname/index.html'));
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```